# How i can find 14 migrations and apply them?

Tags: python, django

[image]

How i can find 14 migrations and apply them? How easy is it to solve this problem?

Comment: Run `python manage.py migrate` and go through the official Django tutorial to learn the basics. It even says in the error message to run that command.

Answer (score 0):

To find migration files, simply look in to your app(s) directories, there will be a directory named `migrations`. Inside the folder, you can see a list of python files like this: `000x_migration_description.py`.

However, to solve your problem, just run `python manage.py migrate`. Django will look for all unapplied migrations and apply them.